# user settings changed on file not changing run time

Tags: c#, application-settings, settings

I have a file with several user and application settings, when I change them run time and then save them, the file is not updated, still, when I re-start the application they are there. Where are they saved?

Also, if I change some of the settings in the file, and then start the application, I cant see those changes in my application, why is that?

I tried to read the documentation related to Settings (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) but I wasn't able to find the awsner.

Comment: You are probably looking at the wrong file. Maybe post some file list / sample.

Comment: I am checkign the configs at the file [executableName].exe.config at the bin/release folder.

Comment: I found out that user settings are stored at %APPDATA/LOCAL and application settings at the file previously indicated... thats the problem.